# Fooling live-video authentication

Tags: privacy, webrtc

I don't know if this is a good site to ask this question but it's the best fit I've found so far.

I've started signing up to cryptocurrency exchanges. Many of them require users to send digital copies of two pieces of ID, one of which must be a passport, in order to verify my identity. Further, they require me to use WebRTC to take a photo of myself holding the passport and a note containing the website name and the current date.

I understand their desire to verify my identity, but passports contain more information than they need (they just need my name and address) and it opens me up to identity theft. Further, as one commentor [found out the hard way](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-safe-to-send-a-copy-of-your-ID-online-to-Bitcoin-exchanges-for-identity-verification/answer/Chris-Beach) nothing prevents exchanges from sharing this information with others, intentionally or otherwise.

I have taken upon myself to digitally alter all information in my passport aside from the name and address to prevent its misuse. I'd like to get your advice on how to fool the WebRTC live video feed.

Is there a browser plugin that allows one to configure the browser to send static images instead of a live video feed?

Alternatively, maybe I could point the webcam at a static image on my computer monitor?

Consider this a white-hat challenge ;)

Comment: er wow this misses on so many points. I mean static images of the same thing? Why not just point the camera at a picture of yourself? How does that fix anything?

Comment: @CandiedOrange the exchange doesn't actually use a video for verification. They are taking a photo using a WebRTC video stream. There is a countdown (5.. 4... 3... 2... 1...) They snap a photo, ask you to approve it, and send it off. So in that sense, a static image would help. I could manipulate that image before sending it off to them.

Comment: What actual problem are you solving by manipulating the image before sending it off to them?

Comment: @CandiedOrange Manipulating information not found on a driver's license (everything aside from my name and address) to incorrect values so that it cannot be abused.

Comment: If you want to redact stuff they don't need just black it out or put your thumb over it. If you're trying to falsify that info you've lost your white hat status.

Comment: @CandiedOrange In theory you're right. In practice, these exchanges insist on receiving unredacted high-quality scans of users' passports. Cryptocurrency exchanges are notoriously bad when it comes to being reasonable and/or providing personalized support to negotiate these things.

Comment: I'm all for the right to anonymity but you have to work with those who respect that. Stop giving your money to those that don't.

Comment: I consider this question as asking to break the security of an existing system - because these identity checks are done for security. But, such questions are off-topic here. If you don't trust the exchange to handle your data properly don't deal with them.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Not really. This question is about ensuring that exchanges do not use redacted information without my knowledge. If they really need it, they will verify it. If they do, they will discover verification fails and complain to me. Security is still in place. The only thing this blocks is exchanges using information they shouldn't without my knowledge.

Comment: @Gili: If you feel that they should live with redacted information just tape over the relevant information on your passport when showing it and see if they will accept it. Trying to present fake information instead is trying to break their security - no matter what your intention is.

Comment: I don't know any product/software for this kind of application. But, I know some image processsing and it is of course doable. You may find easy to use OCR libraries and processing video is not much harder than static images with libaries like OpenCV.

Comment: Exchanges require to see a passport for identity validation usually as a result of KYC and Anti money laundering laws. Often automated processes will lift information like the passport number off of the photo and run it through a validation service. I would suggest trying to defraud a licensed financial entity during government mandated identity checks is not advisable / likely to be highly illegal. It's also extremely likely to be picked up on by the exchange.